# Eclipse shortcut for getting the error context menu

Tags: eclipse

Well the title may be little confusing, but I believe everyone is familiar with the feature that Eclipse usually lets you autocorrect the possible mistakes just by clicking a light bulb 
 icon present at the left margin of the code editor. When we press that light bulb, we get some autocorrect options in a context menu. Is there any available shortcut for that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean Ctrl+1 (Press the Control-Key then without releasing it, press the One-Key)
That should pop up that menu, if the cursor is on the error (in your case between the C and the l from CustomerImpl).

Comment: thanks for providing the info that the position of cursor also matters.